# Meaning of stacklevel in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I came across many function in PyTorch that have `_stacklevel` as argument. Here an example of the [Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#Softmax) module's `forward()` method where it is used:

```
def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return F.softmax(input, self.dim, _stacklevel=5)
```

What does `_stacklevel` mean? What is it good for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stacklevel` is used in python to indicate warning mechanism how far up the stack it has to go to find the line that called the function which issued the warning. For example, the code below makes the warning refer to `deprecation()`’s caller by using `stacklevel=2`, rather than to the source of `deprecation()` itself. `stacklevel=3` would refer to the caller of `deprecation()`’s caller and so on.

```
def deprecation(message):
    warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

See this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) for more information.

Regarding the specific case you mention, in PyTorch's `F.softmax`, `F.softmin`, and `F.log_softmax` functions, this argument is related to the warning issued when `dim` is not specified. However, it seems that it should be dropped since legacy softmax `dim` behavior is gone, or at least clarified in the documentation. At the moment, this is only mentioned on the following open issues from pytorch repo:

- [pytorch/issues/36524](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36524)
- [pytorch/issues/64038](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/64038)

It will probably be fixed or clarified in the future, but for the moment my recommendation is to simply ignore it.